# Select text inside editable node in CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor

I have a CKEditor widget with some tables with editable fields.

I need to select all the text inside the field when a user clicks it, to make changing the text faster.

For now I was able to come up with this:

```
editor = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1;
widget = editor.widgets.instances[0]

$.each(widget.editables, function(e) {
    element = $(this.$);
    element.on( 'click', function( ev ) {
        elementId = editor.document.getActive().getId()
        editor.getSelection().selectElement( editor.document.getById(elementId) );
    });
});
```

Basically, I get all editable elements and bind a click event to them. My problem is only on how to select the text inside the editable element, since currently all I managed to do is select the element itself.

I need to select the text inside the element that I get when calling `editor.document.getById(element)` .

All other questions on StackOverflow show how to get a selection value, but I could not find anything on how to select only the text inside a node.